# Eliminar registros de la base con angular

Tags: java, html, angularjs

Tengo un inconveniente, no puedo realizar la eliminación de los registros en la base.
En mi proyecto tengo el siguiente código:

```
Controlador:

 $scope.typeKeyDelete = function(index){
    $scope.loadTypeKeyFromList(index);
    $scope.typeKey.$delete();
    $scope.typeKeyList();
};

 Controlador de java:

 @RequestMapping(value = "/type_key/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
  public ResponseEntity<TypeKey> delete(HttpServletRequest 
  httpServletRequest, 
  @PathVariable("id") int id){
    typeKeyDAO.delete(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<TypeKey>(HttpStatus.OK);
}

Vista:
 <li data-ng-if="isPermited('TYPE_KEY_DELETE')"><a href="" title="" data-ng-click="typeKeyDelete($index)" onclick="return confirm('¿Está seguro que desea eliminar el tipo de llave?'), location.reload()">Eliminar</a></li>
```

Comment: Sería bueno que especifiques cual es el problema el error o que paso

Comment: Lo que pasa es que pongo eliminar el registro y se sigue visualizando, en la vista y en la base de datos. Gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: Podrías ver con debug si llega a llamarse el método si no no se está llando y también ver la consola del navegador para ver si algo está saliendo

Comment: Buenas noches y gracias, sabes que si le revise así y si está bien la función de eliminar, el problema, de lo que estoy leyendo, puede darse a una configuración en el servidor para que acepte el método http PUT.